# Quick way to change the volume outside of the desktop?

Tags: windows-8, volume-mixer

Is there a quick way to change the volume while inside of the new UI?

Comment: Are you using a PC or laptop. If its laptop then `Fn+down/up arrow` will work like a chram.

Comment: Depends on the laptop. The Fn key is a feature of the keyboard and not visible to the OS. And the Fn keybindings are different for each manufacturer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can press <kbd>[image: Windows]</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to access the Charms bar, then click “Settings” and adjust the volume from there. This also has the nice property of working well with fullscreen applications, such as games.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use [Sharpkeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com) to edit keys, I use it for `VOLUME_UP` and `VOLUME_DOWN` or `MUTE`.
This can be great for keyboards without multimedia keys.